# Delete entire row from Sheet1 if a VLookUp is TRUE (if the value appears in a list on a separate worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to delete an entire row if a particular value appears in a lookup table on another worksheet.

Sheet 1 is called "BARWON" (there are five sheets where I will run this script, but I can adapt that part to run for each worksheet).
The sheet with the LookUp values is called "RemoveUnits", this sheet only has one column (A) which is a list of values that are essentially redundant so I don't want them to take up space in the BARWON sheet.
I don't need to reference any external workbooks, everything is contained within this workbook.

I want to check just the C column of "BARWON" from C3 to C200 and if the value appears anywhere in the list in column A of "RemoveUnits" then I want to delete the entire row (from the BARWON sheet) in which that value appears.

The following is slow and doesn't seem to check the entire range:

```vb
Sub RemoveUnits()

    Dim wsBarwon As Worksheet, wsRemoveUnits As Worksheet
    Dim rngLookup As Range, rngRemove As Range, cell As Range

    Set wsBarwon = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BARWON")
    Set wsRemoveUnits = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RemoveUnits")
    Set rngLookup = wsBarwon.Range("C3:C200")
    Set rngRemove = wsRemoveUnits.Range("A1:A500")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In rngLookup
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngRemove, 0)) Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Entire Rows

- To delete all rows, you need to either loop from the bottom to the top or combine the cells (ranges) into a range union and delete the union in one go.

```vb
Sub RemoveUnitsTEST()
    RemoveUnits "BARWON"
End Sub

Sub RemoveUnits(ByVal TargetSheetName As String)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("RemoveUnits")
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("A1", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TargetSheetName)
    Dim trg As Range:
    Set trg = tws.Range("C3", tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim trIndexes: trIndexes = Application.Match(trg, srg, 0)
    
    Dim turg As Range, tr As Long
    
    For tr = 1 To UBound(trIndexes, 1)
        If IsNumeric(trIndexes(tr, 1)) Then
            If turg Is Nothing Then
                Set turg = trg.Cells(tr)
            Else
                Set turg = Union(turg, trg.Cells(tr))
            End If
        End If
    Next tr
    
    If Not turg Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            turg.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works really well, even better than I had first anticipated. Thank you very much for your help!